# Comparing two URLs with and without https

Tags: python, url, urllib, url-scheme

Is there a way I can compare two URLs regardless of their protocol so that `https://www.google.com` and `www.google.com/` are the same URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

u1 = urlparse('https://www.google.com')
u2 = urlparse('http://www.google.com/')
u3 = urlparse('ftp://www.google.com/som/ting/else')

print(u1.netloc == u2.netloc == u3.netloc)
```

Out:

```
True
```